# How do I copy the data buffer from SDL_LoadWAV to SDL_AudioCVT?

Tags: c++, pointers, sdl-2

This function should load a wav and convert it to the desired format.
My issue is that I can't figure out how to copy the data to the cvt properly.
What I'm gathering from the docs is that the audio data is a Uint8 pointer to a pointer.
I know that it must point to an array of some sort but I have no clue how it is setup.

```
void load_audio()
{
    string full_path = default_path;
    full_path += path;
    if (wav_length > 0)
    {
        SDL_FreeWAV(wav_buffer);
    }
    if (SDL_LoadWAV(full_path.c_str(), &wav_spec, &wav_buffer, &wav_length) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open wav: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return;
    }
    // convert input format to U8 mono 32kHz
    SDL_AudioCVT cvt;
    SDL_BuildAudioCVT(&cvt, wav_spec.format, wav_spec.channels, wav_spec.freq, AUDIO_U8, 1, 32000);
    SDL_assert(cvt.needed);
    cvt.len = wav_length * wav_spec.channels * 2;  // length of original data * 2 for 16bit
    cvt.buf = (Uint8 *) SDL_malloc(cvt.len * cvt.len_mult);

    // How do I copy the data from wav_buffer to cvt.buf ???

    SDL_ConvertAudio(&cvt); // convert
}
```

The wav vars are as follows

```
SDL_AudioSpec wav_spec;
Uint32 wav_length;
Uint8 *wav_buffer;
```

Side note: The wav files I will be loading will always be 16bit

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be memcpy() and the cvt_len var instead of cvt.len

```
// convert input format to U8 mono 32kHz
SDL_AudioCVT cvt;
SDL_BuildAudioCVT(&cvt, wav_spec.format, wav_spec.channels, wav_spec.freq, AUDIO_U8, 1, 32000);
SDL_assert(cvt.needed); // obviously, this one is always needed.
cvt.len = wav_length * wav_spec.channels * 2;  // length of original data * 2 for 16bit
cvt.buf = (Uint8 *) SDL_malloc(cvt.len * cvt.len_mult); // allocate buffer
memcpy(cvt.buf, wav_buffer, wav_length); // copy wav data to cvt buffer
SDL_ConvertAudio(&cvt); // convert
wav_length = cvt.len_cvt; // len_cvt is the actaul length after conversion
memcpy(wav_buffer, cvt.buf, cvt.len_cvt); // copy converted cvt buffer back to wav buffer
```